# GridView templates

Tags: asp.net

Any help on how I could format/structure/template a GridView so that the the contents from an excel spreadsheet's cells would 
display as:

```
<li>"looking to display data from column1 here between the li tags"</li>
    <p>"and data from column2 here between the p tags"</p>

<!-- and so row two from excel / objDataset1 would do the same -->
  <li>"data from column1 here"</li>
    <p>"data from column2 here"</p>

etc...
```

Here is the code I used to get a named range within the excel file into a gridview:

```
 Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
                & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("Spreadsheet.xls") _
                & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    '  original code was:  & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../ExcelData.xls") _ ' ???


    Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    objConn.Open()

    ' Create new OleDbCommand to return the data from the worksheet / RangeName.
    Dim objCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM RangeName", objConn)
    Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect
    Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet()

    ' Fill the DataSet with the information from the worksheet / RangeName.
    objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData") ' ?!?!?

    ' Build 
    GridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView
    GridView1.DataBind()
    objConn.Close()
```

---------------------------- the bit I'm after --------------------------------------

```
 <!-- It doesn't do much a present but it does display the info -->
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="height: 182px" 
    BackColor="Transparent"
    BorderColor="#DEDFDE"
    BorderStyle="None"
    BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4"
    ForeColor="Black"
    GridLines="None">


    <RowStyle BackColor="Transparent"

    />

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />

   <%-- <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />--%>
    <%-- I do not want to show the column header info from the excel file - which is coming through - also --%>


    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Transparent" />

</asp:GridView>
```

I don't even know if I should be using the gridview or something else -  so keep it nice and simple if you can...

Comment: What is it doing now that you don't want it to do?  Or what more do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gridview is a great choice if you're wanting spreadsheet-looking data on a webpage.  That is exactly what it is designed for.

BTW, it is bad form to intermingle `<li`>s with `<p>`s.  The `<p>` and `</p>` can live completely within an `<li>` and `</li>` but the `<li>` element was meant to completely enclose all other elements.  In other words, you should not have any other tags as direct children to a `<ul>`.

EDIT:
Yes, Carpenter, you're close.  No problem having formatting within `<li>`s.  Just put the entire formatting within the `<li>` using divs.  Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.Question {
    background-color: orange;
}
.Answer {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
<li>
  <div>
    <p class="Question">Q: Why is SO so awesome?</p>
    <p class="Answer">A: Because the community writes the questions.</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div>
    <p class="Question">Q: Should I join?</p>
    <p class="Answer">A: Yes, if you want to help the community by upvoting good questions and answers.</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div>
    <p class="Question">Q: Do you have to join?</p>
    <p class="Answer">A: No, you can ask questions and read answers anonymously.</p>
  </div>
</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

And don't worry about using the answer section ... you don't have enough reputation to comment/edit, but you will be closer after the 10 I just gave you by upvoting your question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for commenting withing the answer section first of all Rap - I don't have an Openid so this is a work around that I use here. Thanks for the help too...

I am going for a ol which both has a Question and an answer with each li as it were, and the look of the li then a p tags just looked quite nice to me - layout wise...  should it be li text 
 text then another li... is that alright?

Answer (score 0):

Just showing how I got it to work in the end...  & Any tips on the code?

```
    ' Create connection string variable. Modify the "Data Source" parameter as
    ' appropriate for your environment.
    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
                & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("Spreadsheet.xls") _
                & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    '  original:  & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../ExcelData.xls") _


    Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    objConn.Open()
    ' Create new OleDbCommand to return data from worksheet / RangeName.
    Dim objCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM RangeName", objConn)
    Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect

    ' Create new DataSet to hold information from the worksheet / RangeName.
    Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet()

    ' Fill the DataSet with the information from the worksheet / RangeName.
    objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData")

    ' Create a new DataTable object 
    Dim MyTable = New DataTable
    MyTable = objDataset1.Tables(0)

    ' Find how many rows are in the Rows collection 
    ' of the new DataTable object.
    Dim numrows = MyTable.Rows.Count

    If numrows = 0 Then
        display_htmlstring.InnerHtml = "<p>No records found.</p>"
    Else

        Dim rowashtml As String
        rowashtml = "<ol>"

        For loop1 = 0 To numrows - 1
' the excel rangename has column headings of Problem & Answers
            rowashtml = rowashtml & "<li>" & Server.HtmlEncode(MyTable.Rows(loop1).Item("Problem")) _
              & "<p>" & Server.HtmlEncode(MyTable.Rows(loop1).Item("Answers")) & "</p></li>"

        Next loop1
        display_htmlstring.InnerHtml = rowashtml & "</ol>"
    End If

------------------------ the girdView is gone and I am now using just ---------------

<div id="display_htmlstring" runat="server">
  </div>
```

Thanks again Rap for the help (li"Stuff can be here hopefuly"p"and here too"p li)